# Dowload file from cmd or powershell corrupted

Tags: apache, powershell, cmd, sha512

I have a simple script that must download a .exe file from apache httpd server, and when I run a `Get-FileHash` script on the downloaded file, It isn't the same as the uploaded file. Even each time I download the file, the hash is different.
I've tried downloading through cmd, and same result. I'm sure it isn't an upload problem, since the apache httpd server is running in my local machine through docker , and the `Get-FileHash` in the "uploaded file" (local folder read by docker) is the same as the original file.

This is the relevant part of the script, and the output.

```
$filename = "C:\chocoPack\aloha.10.6.2155.nupkg"
if (!(Test-Path $filename)) {
 (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile("http://localhost:9999/aloha.10.6.2155.nupkg", "$filename")
 $hash = Get-FileHash -Path $filename -Algorithm SHA512
 if ($hash.Hash -eq "06AC8843472DE63AD6074DFA1E825F4F68C67D54C5526A9F7001CD30047FE62FFFC02D5E468F9E2F5965357FB65975302DDB8C379C03891277CC8193F768DBF0"){
    Write-Host ('Yayy')
    Write-host $hash.Hash
 } else {
    Write-Host $hash.Hash
    Remove-Item $filename
 }
}
```

this produces a lot of differents Hashes, that almost never match with the original hash, like

`FF89FA909ACD8D2468E915E71180341AF3734E42B679B23BCE8A832209EE26AD6BF55A670C3E6D18273181D6E72FE8982C78D6A83A4868F558CCDBF9CC5B7EE2`

`092EFE9A7FBBF7934F0FE99CAA54A4AD2CECCED5DDD9B942DB963A633A3073657BB350493FD60385E577C349DE78A4799AB58DE78C7621B1AD58BC18409ADE13`

etc..

any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Are you sure that you're downloading the actual file and not an error message?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I've tried running the `Get-FileHash` in the downloaded file in a separated script, and result was the same

Comment: Ahh, `System.Net.WebClient.DownloadFile` is not synchronous. In other words, the rest of your script runs before the file download is even finished. Try using `Invoke-WebRequest` with an `-OutFile` parameter instead.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've also tried Invoke-WebRequest, and even cUrl and same result produced :/

Comment: `curl` is an Alias for `Invoke-Webrequest` in Powershell, so unless you have installed a 3rd party `curl.exe` and called it explicitly, those two things are the same. There is no way a successfully (and finished!) downloaded file has a different hash than than on the server, let alone a different hash every time. Your mistake must be somewhere else.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I understand that hash must match if the download was succesfully , but I can't figure out where the error is. The code is very simple and the error doesn't have sense. Let me add that I ran the script in a while loop, and after a random number of tries (sometimes 200 times) the hashes match... It doesn't make sense for me

Comment: It's hard to say. Open the original file and the downloaded file in a hex editor and compare. Think where the differences you see might come from.

Comment: I finally found the issue. Apparently, It's a bug in Docker for Windows ... In Linux Docker, It works perfectly

Comment: Okay... when you look at the file differences in a hex editor, can you determine where things go wrong? Is something in there that looks suspicious? Does the same happen when you try with images or plain text files?